# Cut string at space with a regex but watch for umlauts?

Tags: php, regex, diacritics

This is my code:

```
if (preg_match('/^.{1,22}\b/s', $myString, $match)) {
    $name = $match[0];
}
```

It cuts a string after 22 chars and at a whitespace. Problem is, it does not work if there are unmlauts like ü in the string.

- That works: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
- That does **not** work: 12345678 - Schlüsselband

Any ideas how to fix that?

Comment: It should work after you add `/u`: `'/^.{1,22}\b/us'`

Comment: Great, that did the trick, thanks a lot!